# Contracting Bianchi Identity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, curvature, conventions

Bianchi Identity is given as

$$R^n_{ikl;m}+R^n_{imk;l}+R^n_{ilm;k}=0 \tag{1}$$

$R^n_{ikl;m}$ is the Riemann/Curvature Tensor with covariant derivative with respect to m. To contract on $i$,$k$ and $l$,$n$, I do the following

$$g^l_ng^{ik}(R^n_{ikl;m}+R^n_{imk;l}+R^n_{ilm;k})=0 \tag{2}$$

$$R^l_{l;m}+R^n_{m;n}+R^n_{m;n}=0 \tag{3}$$

Since $R^l_{l;m}$ is scalar (right?), so

$$R^l_{l;m}=\frac{\partial R}{\partial x^m} \tag{4}$$

So I get,

$$R^n_{m;n}=-\frac{1}{2}R^l_{l;m}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial R}{\partial x^m} \tag{5}$$

However, the book doesn't have the negative sign in equation $(5)$. What did I do wrong? Anything wrong when I contract the 3rd term in from $(2)$ to $(3)$? Thanks!

Comment: The Ricci tensor is defined by $R_{ij} = R^k{}_{ikj}$. Contracting one upstairs and one downstairs index on the  Riemann tensor does not generally give you the Ricci tensor. You need to use the symmetries of the Riemann tensor to move the dummy indices into the first and third positions in each of your three terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this link for a proof with all the minus signs correct: 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_covariant_derivatives

Basically, you pick up some minus signs by permuting the indices of the Riemann tensor, which you need to do in order to write it as the Ricci tensor.